# LESS: How do I change the color of the header? I tried, but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, less

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="less/less.js" href="css/style.less">

</head>

<header> This is a header. </header>

</html>
```

style.less:

```
@light-blue: @blue + #111;

#header {
  color: @light-blue;
}
```

And the header still shows up just regular black. Not light blue. There are no error messages in the console.

Comment: did you try to remove the # symbol from the css "#header"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Perhaps it isn't finding style.less? But there are no errors in the console...

Comment: Can you put it on fiddle?

Comment: I can't find less on there as an extension.

Comment: You have to specify the  @blue put a value to it

Comment: I think the problem is, it seems to not be finding less/less.js, after I added the code <script src="less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: have you properly installed less, in other words, have you downloaded the proper needed files before you try to link them to your code?

Comment: I did npm install -g less. I can see less as one of the node modules.

Comment: @Hellothere, install your less properly and then refer to the answer of KAD

Comment: make sure the file paths you are using in your html really represent the relative location of the files themselves

Comment: Do I need to go through node modules and find less.js somewhere in there? I have written another app with node and socket.io, where I could just do socket/socket.io and it found it just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `#header`, this means you are calling an element having an `id="header"`, change it to `header` to capture the header element.

Also, you are confusing the js and less links. Less shall be embedded to your code as follows :

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less" />
<script src="less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, set the @blue with a valid color :

```
@blue: #5B83AD;
@light-blue: @blue + #111;
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I even tried changing it to id="header" in the HTML, with #header in the style.less, but it still doesn't change the color..

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't change the color. Oh, but now it responded with a not found error for less/less.js... Hmm. I have less in the node modules...

Comment: @Hellothere A browser won't find `less.js` in node modules (How can it know where to look?)... I.e. you either have to copy it to `less/less.js` (relative to your page path) just as it's written in the HTML or specify full path instead (the latter won't work of course when you move your pages to a server). Or (obviously) set it to use some CDN e.g. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.js`